# How can I stop legionaires attacking me during a mission?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have to report to Legate Rikke on Compelling Tribute and I jumped on the horse I arrived on only to realise that it said steal horse. So I jumped straight off and carried on the mission and when I arrived back Legate Rikke just wants to kill me. I've tried waiting for two days but it's not working, what should I do?

Comment: Trying sheathing your weapons to yield to him.

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if you have a bounty, if you do you could try going to the hold capital which if i recall this one is in riften.   if you pay off your bounty it may reset their attitude towards you.    If that does not work however you could always reload a previous save if you have one.

Legate Rikke may also be tied to solitude so check to see if you can pay a bounty there.

Answer (score 4):

Yield and pay your bounty, or, if you are Thane of the hold where you are wanted, you should be able to tell the guard to look the other way by pulling rank.

NOTE: This only works once.

Comment: Note that this only works one time.

Answer (score 0):

Take her far from the camp and fight her until she falls (but doesn't die). Then just talk to her again, back at the camp site.